# Save textfile in the folder that the program/exe exists in with one click of a button?

Tags: html, windows, vb.net, save, root

Hello i have a simple program that opens up a text file and changes it and then what i want to do is save a text file when you click the "convert" button to the directory that the exe exists in e.g. "C:\Users\Beaudean\Desktop--Distro--" etc. so say i have a richtextbox with the text in it i want to save and a button called "convert", when i click convert it will save it in the programs root folder with the name "main.html" and i also want it to overwrite any file with the same name. thank you very much :)

Comment: While, all the answers below, are correct and respond to your question, I would point that writing to the same folder where your main exe exist is not allways possible due to permissions constraint introduced by latest MS Operating System (Vista,Seven). In that case a better approach will be to create a personal directory for your app data in the Documents or in the ProgramData folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim appDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
Dim filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDir, "main.html")
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text)
```

[HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! but i get an error with [ System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, Text) ] this part of the code, it says "URI formats are not supported." ?

Comment: @happycamper1221: Sorry, use `GetExecutingAssembly().Location` instead(corrected).

Comment: could you please give me the full code example like before - I'm not that good a vb. thank you :)

Comment: @happycamper1221: As i've mentioned, i've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @happycamper1221 If you wrap your class in a dll that you will use from your executable GetExecutingAssembly().Location will return the path of your dll and not of your executable. GetEntryAssembly().Location returns always the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the location of your executable:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach,

```
Dim myWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\main.html")

myWriter.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)

myWriter.Close()
```

Hope this might be helpful